# How to delete all the login/membership information?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There is an asp.net mvc 4 website. The users want to re-start the web application from scratch. What's the best way to clear all the login/membership information. Just use Sql server management studio to delete the records in all the tables? (webpages_*, and UserProfile)?

There is an added column in table `UserProfile` which refers to an user defined table.

Or maybe just drop the whole database using SSMS? Or delete all the tables (include the __MigrationHistory) in the database?

Comment: You're using confusing terms. Do you mean you want to delete all registered user accounts from a SqlMembershipProvider?

Comment: Then take a look at [`SqlMembershipProvider.DeleteUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.deleteuser.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In the controller you use for handling the users, you can create an action method to delete a user. In this example it's the current user that will be deleted, including all related data.

```
public ActionResult DeleteMe()
{
  Membership.DeleteUser(User.Identity.Name, deleteAllRelatedData: true);
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

To call the action method above just add the following code in a view to display a button...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteMe","Account"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete my account" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

...or this, if you want to display a link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete my account", "DeleteMe", "Account")
```

If you want the function to delete another user and not yourself you can modify the action method above and do something like this:

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser(string userName)
{
  Membership.DeleteUser(userName, deleteAllRelatedData: true);
}
```

Note that you need to add a bit more of security to this to check that the user calling this method actually has the right to do it...but this is the basics regarding how to delete a user.